# how to get time value from youtube playlist

Tags: php, xml, video, youtube

i want to get all videos time from youtube playlist...

check this link..

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilJP08u8jq0&list=PLCK7NnIZXn7g3gvXsTDFpLkihKOIkNKuj
```

on this link have 3 videos. its all videos duration is 52:42..

```
1 > 18:39
2 > 18:20
3 > 15:43

All duration > 52:42
```

so i want to get all duration from youtube playlist.. but that time want from php... so how to `get youtube playlist all videos time value from php`.. thanks for read.plz help me for do it.

Comment: your question is clearly missing to show research effort.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Get complete playlist listing for a YouTube User via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067007/get-complete-playlist-listing-for-a-youtube-user-via-api)

In particular, you can get all available entries for a playlist feed using this zend function:

```
$playlistListFeed = $yt->retrieveAllEntriesForFeed($yt->getPlaylistListFeed($userName));
```

You could then iterate through each entry of the feed and sum the time.

Comment: this is not support for my question